# linux date command convert arbitrary date time to utc

Tags: linux, date

How do I convert an arbitrary date and time to UTC using the 'date' command in Linux?

Using the following format just prints my specified time and doesn't convert it.

```
# /usr/bin/date -u --date="2016-06-21 01:00:00"
Tue Jun 21 01:00:00 UTC 2016
```

Using the current system time does seem to convert to UTC correctly

```
# /usr/bin/date
Tue Jun 21 08:48:44 EDT 2016
#/usr/bin/date -u 
Tue Jun 21 12:48:55 UTC 2016
```

Comment: The OS usually keeps date internally in UTC. It just displays it accordingly to your time zone definitions. So, `date -u` converts nothing. There can be no correct local to UTC conversion for all the times in time zones supporting day time saving.

Comment: it is unclear what you mean here with _Using the following format just prints my specified time and doesn't convert it_.

Answer (score 4):

You can use command substitution to get your desired output. The command inside parentheses will return the number of seconds since epoch. Then `date -u --date` will format the date to UTC.

```
date -u --date=@$(date "+%s" --date="2016-06-21 01:00:00")
Tue Jun 21 05:00:00 UTC 2016
```

The above command will convert an arbitrary date and time to UTC as it is required.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have the date in UTC, prepend the region:

```
$ date
Tue Jun 21 15:00:10 CEST 2016
$ TZ=UTC date
Tue Jun 21 13:00:10 UTC 2016
```

If you want to use a specific date, just use `-d` normally:

```
$ TZ=UTC date -d"yesterday"
Mon Jun 20 13:00:55 UTC 2016
```